# Sublime cannot find the module in order to run the package. (importError no module named ___)

Tags: plugins, package, sublimetext3, git-clone, package-control

I've cloned 2 repositories from the Github pages which are [HyperHelpAuthor](https://github.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/HyperHelpAuthor) and [HyperHelpCore](https://github.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/hyperhelpcore) to run a package called [SnAPI](https://github.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/SnAPI). But Sublime Text keeps throwing an error that can't handle on my own.

> ImportError: No module named 'hyperhelpcore.core'.

This error pops up on the console when I clone **SnAPI** package. Eventually, none of those packages are working. First one, HyperHelpAuthor, is successfully installed and I can see bunch of the items on menubar but all of them are colored by grey which is unavailable to run.

Second package, HyperHelpCore is just simply does not appear on my editor.

Last but not least, SnAPI is also does not appear on my command palette including the error above.

Are there any ways to fix this problem?

Comment: As a an extra side note to my answer below, the help in SnAPI is currently a little behind the curve of recent. I am however currently in the process of updating the Help system in general, so that I can bring it back up to speed with everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hyperhelpcore` is not a package, it's a dependency that the other packages depend on in order to provide the system (although I am, ironically, currently in the process of changing how that works).

As a side note, `HyperHelpAuthor` is not needed to run `SnAPI`; it's a separate package (that is currently pre-alpha) that aims to provide the services needed to make authoring help using HyperHelp easier.

The usual way to install everything would be the following instructions (but, see below first, since you already cloned the repositories):

1. Use `Package Control: Add Repository` from the command palette
2. In the panel that appears in the bottom of the window, enter the URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/SublimePackages/master/unreleased-packages.json
3. Use `Package Control: Install Package` from the command palette and choose `SnAPI` from the list (or `HyperHelpAuthor`, if you want that as well)

However, since you've already cloned the repositories, the easiest thing for you to do would be to use `Package Control: Install Local Dependency` from the command palette, and choose `hyperhelpcore` from the list.

Note that all of the packages are name sensitive; you should clone them with the same name as they appear on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. As you have mentioned above, I should have selected `hyperhelpcore` on the `Local Dependency` of the `Package Control`. Now it works smoothly.